# JavaScript or jQuery for print a row entry in a Cheque format every line of table should be print separately by print link

Tags: javascript, jquery

[this is my Django based project and I want to print this table by row the print link is in the table that print particular row entries in a format like a Cheque please suggest JavaScript or Jquery for this]

```js
<script>
function Print() {
  var docprint = window.open('about:blank', '_blank'); //new page
  var oTable = document.getElementById('result_tbl').rows.item(0); //get the 1st row by a selector
  docprint.document.open();
  docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Ashley Mattresses</title>'); //write HEAD section
  docprint.document.write('</head><body><center>'); //write BODY tag and center tag for printing
  docprint.document.write(oTable.innerHTML); //select the TR's HTML and add it to the new page
  docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); //close BODY tag
  docprint.document.close();
  docprint.print();
  docprint.close();
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="print-content">
<b><u><h2 align="center">Duplicate Cheque</h2></b></u>
<table id="result_tbl" class="display" >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>To_Pay</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Amount_In_Words</th>
    <th>Cheque_No</th>
    <th>Account_No</th>
    <th>Cheque_Date</th>
    <th>Print</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody> 
 {% for duplicate in duplicates %}
  <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
 <td>{{duplicate.topay}}</td>
 <td>{{duplicate.amount1}}</td>
 <td>{{duplicate.amount_string}}</td>
    <td>{{duplicate.chequeno}}</td>
    <td>{{duplicate.accountno}}</td>
    <td>{{duplicate.chequedate}}</td>
 <td><a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a></td>   
  
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hey Yashwardhan can u show my both image i think your edit remove my one pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below exam

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
     <style>       
        @media print {
            #result_tbl tbody tr {
                display: none;
            }

            .printRowStyle {
                display: block!important;
            }

            #result_tbl tbody tr td:first-child,#result_tbl thead tr 
             th:first-child,#result_tbl tbody tr td:last-child,#result_tbl 
            thead tr th:last-child{
                   display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        function printRow(obj) {
            $(obj).closest('tr').addClass('printRowStyle');
            window.print();
            $(obj).closest('tr').removeClass('printRowStyle');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="result_tbl" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>To_Pay</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Amount_In_Words</th>
                <th>Cheque_No</th>
                <th>Account_No</th>
                <th>Cheque_Date</th>
                <th>Print</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a onclick="printRow(this)">Print</a></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a onclick="printRow(this)">Print</a></td>

            </tr>

            <tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no but if i use this css than it will hide my all table entries

Comment: u need to write css in @@media print like
 @@media print {
            #result_tbl tbody tr {
                display: none;
            }

            .printRowStyle {
                display: block!important;
            }
        }

Comment: i have also updated my code, please see if it works for you

Comment: yup its working but it prints whole page like a screenshot not the particular row entries that i wanted

Comment: yes <tr>
    <td class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
 <td>{{duplicate.topay}}</td>
 <td>{{duplicate.amount1}}</td>
 <td>{{duplicate.amount_string}}</td>
    <td>{{duplicate.chequeno}}</td>
    <td>{{duplicate.accountno}}</td>
    <td>{{duplicate.chequedate}}</td>
 <td><a onclick="printRow()">Print</a></td>
  </tr>

Comment: it should work with the above code, let me try some another solution

Comment: thank you so much for giving your valuable time to my problem.. i tried a lot but find helpless please help if u can

Comment: glad to help, i expect you have deleted your print function, that you were using earlier.

Comment: yes i use your function only this time can i include mine also

Comment: i dnt understand where i do modifications please tell me

Comment: hey this will print thead and first row what ever row i clicked the all above row is also printed but my question is diffrent i want only input of particular row that i want to print on a blank page like it picks only topay,amount,amount-in_words,chequeno,chequedate and account no not pick that particular field but pick only the input entry of field

Comment: please see the picture that i have mention in my question i want accordingly

Comment: updated css and jquery function, please try node, it will hide first and last column on print page

Comment: is their not a relevant way to hide everything except that row entry